# JS event when an audio/video decoding error occurs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have a system that can keep track of many kinds of files.

For certain types (audio/video in this question's case), I want to be able to show them to the user. However, not all systems/browsers/environments can play all types of media.

I would rather not keep track of what types are playable, but rather attempt to play them and report to the user if they are not playable.

I have tried to accomplish this by simply setting up an audio element, and attempt to add a hook to the error being thrown when it happens:

```
let previewAudio = $(' <audio controls>\n' +
    '  <source src="/api/v1/media/fileAttachments/'+ fileGetData.id + '/data" type="'+latestMetadata.mimeType+'">\n' +
    '</audio> ');
previewAudio.on("error", function (e){
    let code = previewAudio[0].error.code
    console.log("Finished loading audio. Error: ", e);
    console.log("Error code: ", code);
});
FileAttachmentView.previewContainer.append(previewAudio);
```

When given a `.wav` file, I get the following errors (which is fine):

[image]

However, the associated hook for handling the `error` event never fires.

I have also tried `abort`, `loadeddata`, `loadedmetadata`, `loadedmetadata`, `suspend`, `stalled`

What event gets thrown when the browser can't play the file due to a file type or decode error?